# Spring is error with Ant build file

Tags: java, spring, ant

I used to build and run automatically with NetBean IDE. It works fine with Spring. However, now I want to write my own Ant build file. It builds successfully, the only thing is the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext seems like it can't find the class path at runtime. I am using Spring 3.0.5 with the following libraries, put in lib folder:

```
org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-sources-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-sources-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-sources-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-sources-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

The folder structure:

> DevFortress
>
> +---lib
>
> +---src
>
> ```
>     + config
>
>     +.......
> ```
>
> +---build
>
> ```
>     +----classes
>
>     +----jar
> ```

I want to get a context from my devFortress.xml: 
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("DevFortress.xml");
Originally, the DevFortress.xml is in config package in src package. However, I just want to make my program run, so I put it into lib folder, classes and jar as well, but it's hopeless.

Here is my build file:

```
<project name="DevFortress" basedir="." default="main">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="config.dir" value="${src.dir}/config"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="main-class" value="Controller.Main"/>

    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${config.dir}" includes="**/*.xml"/>
    </path>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile = "${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends = "jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
</project>
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried just including the configuration files into the jar creation process

Comment: copy the configuration file to the classes.dir before generating the jar file, this way it will be in the jar

Comment: Aww, I got another problem. I was mistaken. I used the spring framework 2.0.5, which is built in NetBean, it works. However, when I download on the official website, and replace those old built-in libraries with the new ones (i removed all in the libraries package in NetBean). The program can't run now. It can't file the class path anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Also, my XML schema in Spring XML file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC01.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.6.SEC01.xsd"/>
```